# DynamoDB Insert with smallest range key when sparse range keys present for a partition key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

For a specific partition key, I need to put an item in the table with smallest range key possible.

eg. If my table already has these four items 
(partition key, range key) - (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 5) (2, 1)
and I want to put an item for partition key 1, then I'll put (1, 3) in the table.

One way I can do is querying all the range keys for my required partition key. But I guess it would be a very expensive operation.

Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Without knowing anything else about the data, there is no better way to find the first available unused sort key.

### Longer Answer

Note that this general question (finding the least unused integer index) has been asked many times for SQL databases. Although SQL offers various ways to find unused keys (left outer joins, correlated subqueries, stored procedures), the performance is never better than scanning the index space as you have proposed.

To find keys faster, you would need to know in advance the available sort keys in the partition.  That would likely involve creating and maintaining some sort of free space list (perhaps in a separate Dynamo table).  Creating the free list for any partition would require a scan of all its sort keys, but subsequent insert operations could consult the free list to more efficiently find the next available key. Of course, you would have to keep the free list up to date for any insertions & deletions.

Finally, take a moment to consider how your solution will be affected by concurrency and DynamoDB's optimistic locking strategy. If multiple processes are writing to the same partition at the same time, the sort key value that is available when you find it might be unavailable by the time you go to do the insertion.